# Circular reference in domain model using c# struct

Tags: c#, circular-reference

What happens when there is a circular reference between two structs? How does memory allocation work for the example below or would it yield and error?

```
    public struct MultipleChoiceQuestion
    {
        public IEnumerable<Option> Options;
    }

    public struct Option
    {
        public MultipleChoiceQuestion Question;
    }
```

Comment: as a rule of thumb you shouldn't have reference types within a struct

Comment: @BrokenGlass, do you have more info, maybe a link for further reading. TIA

Comment: @BrokenGlass no strings then? :p

Comment: yaya got me there ;-) string is very special anyway. @John K: I guess the problem is only if you have a reference to a mutable reference type, the copy and comparison semantics always get me there, so I personally try to avoid most reference types altogether in structs (which I use rarely anyway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Options` field in `MultipleChoiceQuestion` is just a reference here, which will be `null` by default. The `Question` field in `Option` is a value of type `MultipleChoiceQuestion` which will have its default value by default. There's no problem here (other than a questionable design in more ways than one).

A *genuine* circular reference leading to a logical memory problem will fail to compile:

```
struct Foo
{
    Bar bar;
}

struct Bar
{
    Foo foo;
}
```

> Test.cs(6,9): error CS0523: Struct member 'Foo.bar' of type 'Bar' causes a cycle in the struct layout
>   Test.cs(11,9): error CS0523: Struct member 'Bar.foo' of type 'Foo' causes a cycle in the struct layout

Comment: You are spot on Jon. I had a bit of a Brain freeze / blind spot forgetting that the the list would be a reference type.

Answer (score 2):

Question (property) is encapsulation; the question is part of the outer struct, via a field.

Options, however, is a ***reference*** to an external object that yields one or more Options; these will be copied each time.

There are several other mistakes here:

- mutable structs: EVIL
- public fields: EVIL
- the Options would be better as a list; not all enumerables are repeatable
- they aren't "values" - so they should not be structs; use classes instead

IMO:

```
public class MultipleChoiceQuestion
{
    private readonly List<Option> options
        = new List<Option>();
    public IList<Option> Options {get { return options; } }
}

public class Option
{
    public MultipleChoiceQuestion Question {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MultipleChoiceQuestion` will simply have a reference (pointer) to an object that is IEnumerable, so the size of that struct on the stack will be a single IntPtr (4 bytes on an x86 machine).

The `Option` struct will have the same size, because it contains only the `MultipleChoiceQuestion` struct.