# Why can't structs contain nullable circular references?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, circular-reference

I understand why structs can't contain circular references which lead to logical memory problems, but why doesn't a nullable reference circumvent this limitation? For example:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo? bar;
}
```

Obviously this could very easily lead to stack overflows and circular references, if one wasn't careful, but shouldn't `bar` be a pointer to another `Foo` instance, and default to `null`? Or (more likely) do I not understand how nullable value types are laid out in memory?

(My background knowledge consists mainly of information from [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573943/circular-reference-in-domain-model-using-c-sharp-struct).)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, not quite.  A nullable value type is really an instance of `Nullable<>` with a value type as the generic parameter.  The question mark is just a shorthand.

`Nullable` is a struct, and therefore is a value type.  Since it retains a reference to the `Foo` struct, you still have a circular reference consisting of value types.

Answer (score 7):

`Nullable<T>` is a struct which looks like this (excluding constructors etc):

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
{
    private readonly T value;
    private readonly bool hasValue;
}
```

As that's a *value* type, your `Foo` would end up looking a bit like this:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo barValue;
    bool hasBarValue;
}
```

Now hopefully it's more obvious that that's a problem :)

Comment: As I suspected - my problem was not knowing how `Nullable` was laid out in memory. This makes a lot more sense now!

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yup - think about what it would look like as `Foo` is a value type...

Answer (score 5):

`Foo? bar` is a shortcut for

```
Nullable<Foo> bar;
```

`Nullable<T>` is a struct that roughly looks like this:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
{
    private readonly T value;
    private readonly bool hasValue;
    //..
}
```

In the case of `Foo`, `Nullable<Foo>` would hold a `Foo`, which in turn holds a `Nullable<Foo>` which in turn...

Answer (score 2):

As you probably realize, a struct can't have a circular reference because when you lay the struct out in memory, you have to include storage inside the struct for each of its members.  A cyclical definition requires an infinite amount of storage:

- A struct with two `Int32` members requires 8 bytes (`2 * sizeof(Int32)`); similarly, a struct with four `Int32` members requires 16 bytes.
- If a struct `S` has two `Int32` members plus one `S` member, it would need `2 * sizeof(Int32) + sizeof(S)`.
- But if `sizeof(S) = 2 * sizeof(Int32) + sizeof(S)`, we have infinite recursion, and we can't allocate memory for the struct; recursive definitions are therefore illegal.

Now, assume `sizeof(Nullable<T>) = sizeof(bool) + sizeof(T)` (see Jon Skeet's answer).  Consider a struct `S` with this definition:

```
struct S
{
    int _someField;
    S? _someOtherField;
}
```

In this case, `sizeof(S) = sizeof(Int32) + sizeof(Nullable<S>)`.

Replacing `sizeof(Nullable<S>)` with `sizeof(bool) + sizeof(S)`, we get

`sizeof(S) = sizeof(Int32) + sizeof(bool) + sizeof(S)`

Again, infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

*structs are value types. So, the nested struct creates a memory structure that takes an **infinite** amount of ram. Classes are reference types. So, the nested class creates a memory structure that could be infinite, but at initialization, it is still small.*

Comment: I understand this - I was missing that `Nullable` is a generic struct, not a pointer to `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is walking the struct to determine if there is a cycle.

While reference types contained in structs will be put in the heap and the compiler will treat them differently when looking for cycles, the real type of a nullable type is Nullable is a struct.  So the compiler sees a struct Nullable and considers it a circular reference.

There is a way to get around this - inherit from an interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
}

public struct Foo : IFoo
{
    IFoo Foo;
}
```

Because interfaces are a level of indirection, the compiler will treat your struct like a reference type.